# Convert timestamp as string

Tags: go

I want to get a timestamp as string. If I use `string` conversion I got no error but the output is not readable.
Later, I want us it as a part of a filename.
It looks like a question mark for e.g. �
I found some examples like this: https://play.golang.org/p/bq2h3h0YKp
not solves completely me problem. thanks

```
now := time.Now()      // current local time
sec := now.Unix()      // number of seconds since January 1, 1970 UTC
fmt.Println(string(sec))
```

How could I get the timestamp as string?

Comment: Do you want to printed as seconds or with an specifics format?? Like ``January 1, 1970``

Comment: in seconds its good enough for me. I usually use yyyy-mm-dd-hh-mm-ss thats then best for me

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something like this works for me

```golang
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "strconv"
    "time"
)

func main() {
    now := time.Now()
    unix := now.Unix()
    fmt.Println(strconv.FormatInt(unix, 10))
}
```

Comment: that helps me to search next step. for my filenames i now use: `var re = regexp.MustCompile(`[\W]+`)
s3 := re.ReplaceAllString(time.Now().Format(time.RFC3339), `-`)`

Answer (score 1):

Here are two examples of how you can convert a unix timestamp to a string.

The first example (`s1`) uses the `strconv` package and its function `FormatInt`. The second example (`s2`)  uses the `fmt` package ([documentation](https://golang.org/pkg/fmt/)) and its function `Sprintf`.

Personally, I like the `Sprintf` option more from an aesthetic point of view. I did not check the performance yet.

```
package main

import "fmt"
import "time"
import "strconv"

func main() {
    t := time.Now().Unix() // t is of type int64
    
    // use strconv and FormatInt with base 10 to convert the int64 to string
    s1 := strconv.FormatInt(t, 10)
    fmt.Println(s1)
    
    // Use Sprintf to create a string with format:
    s2 := fmt.Sprintf("%d", t)
    fmt.Println(s2)
}
```

Golang Playground: https://play.golang.org/p/jk_xHYK_5Vu